# How to construct the auxiliary function for this?

Tags: calculus

> Let $f(x)$ be twice differentiable and $f(0)=0$. Prove that there
>   exists a $\xi \in \left(-\frac{\pi}{2},\frac{\pi}{2}\right)$ such that
>   $f''(\xi)=f(\xi)(1+2\tan^2 \xi).$

I guess, we must construct a function $F(x)$, and apply MVT over $\left(-\frac{\pi}{2},0\right)$ and $\left(0,\frac{\pi}{2}\right)$ separately. But I failed for this. Who can help?

Comment: You'll find a solution by Tash [here](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c7h547815p3174690) of this Olympiad problem (IMC 2013)